# Use request during traversal

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm currently implementing adding some API endpoint to our existing Pyramid application. We use [traversal](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/traversal.html) throughout our project so I'm bound by that.

At one point of our traversal we reach a `User` object. These has a `__getitem__` method that allows to retrieve users by ID or username. Now I need to add a way to return 'me', the curently authenticated user (authentication is done beforehand, we can assume the the user is authenticated).

What would be the best way to do this? Since this is done during traversal I don' get passed the `Request` object which would have the user attached to it. I can't use a simple URL map since the traversal need to continue below the user.

Currently I'm resorting to use [pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_request()](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/threadlocal.html#pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_request) whichs documentation is clearly stating that I *should not use it if I can avoid it*. The question is: Can I?

Comment: your root factory does get passed the request though. so your root can keep a handle to it, and then I would pass that through the initializer to all the child objects in the traversal. http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/traversal.html#the-resource-tree

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the request object from the root factory:

Observe my current app's root factory:

```
def RootFactory(request):
  if "debug_toolbar" in request.path or "/static/" in request.path:
    return

  request.user = UserObject(request)


  return BootmapLoader(slug='',page=home_page,request=request)
```